# How to change the color of the command prompt in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

For example I do

```
var1 = %{someprop: 123}
IO.inspect var1
```

I need the background of the line to be yellow and the text color is black. How I can do it?

Comment: Do you want this in `iex` or when you run your script with `elixir foo.exs`?

Comment: If there is a significant difference, then I would like to know both options.

Comment: Unless you meant you want to change the default behavior of inspect itself, then my answer will work with both.

Comment: This blog post on how to change `iex` defaults http://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2017/12/29/iex.exs-to-the-rescue might be of any value as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Changing the color of the text or its background can be achieved using the functions in `IO.ANSI`. You can define your own `inspect` function which changes the background to yellow, the text to black, and prints the inspected value:

```
defmodule A do
  def my_inspect(term) do
    IO.puts IO.ANSI.format([:yellow_background, :black, inspect(term)])
  end
end

A.my_inspect %{someprop: 123}
```

Output:

[image]